# Wake a computer connected directly by ethernet

Tags: wake-on-lan

I have two linux computers connected directly using the NIC on each and an ethernet cable. There is no router connecting them.

According to ethtool both computers support WOL and are configured to do so, but when I try sending the magic packet to the MAC address of the offline computer it fails to turn on.

Is it even possible to WOL without a router between the machines?